Stated Unproved Weierstrass Function Properties on Exam
A really long time ago on an analysis exam (that I bombed) I stated without proof:

The Weierstrass function has the Luzin N property.

Don't remember if this was for some "provide a counterexample problem," but anyway here are the defns of the things I'm referring to:

Weierstrass function - The very wiggly function with the Fourier series.

Luzin N - a function has this property if it maps sets of (Lebesgue) measure zero to sets of measure zero (ex. f(x) = x, counter ex. Cantor function)


I was hoping it was true but I ended up getting no points for this lol. But then it seems like no one really even knows if this is true. Was wondering if you guys had any thoughts on this (whether it is true/false and proof or if this problem is an open problem). I don't have a good idea as to how to approach this problem. Thanks.

The Weierstrass function does not have Luzin N-property, since it is continuous and nowhere differentiable. It can be proved that continuous functions that satisfy Luzin N-property are differentiable on a set of positive Lebesgue measure. This fact is attributed to Banach in the following book:

Saks - Theory of integral - Theorem IX.7.9.


Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be continuous and nowhere differentiable. We show that $f$ does not have the Luzin N property. This is enough since the Weierstrass function is continuous and nowhere differentiable.
Let us consider a closed interval $I\subset \mathbb{R}$. Being differentiable at $x_1$ in the interior of $I$ means $$\lim _{x_2 \rightarrow x_1 ; x_2 \in I \backslash\{x_1\}} \frac{f(x_2)-f(x_1)}{x_2-x_1}$$ exists. Since $f$ is not differentiable, for all $L>0$ we have that (swapping $x_1$ and $x_2$ if needed)
$$
f(x_2)-f(x_1)>L(x_2-x_1).
$$
Since $f$ is continuous, $f([x_1, x_2])$ is an interval containing $f(x_1)$ and $f(x_2)$. Thus
$$
\lambda(f([x_1, x_2]))>L\lambda([x_1, x_2]),
$$
where $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure. Moreover, for any $y$ in the interior of $f(I)$ (which is almost all points in $f(I)$), we can find interval $[a, b]\subset I$ whose image under $f$ contains $y$.
A Vitali cover of a set $A\subset \mathbb{R}$ is a collection of closed intervals such that every point in $A$ is covered by an arbitrarily small interval in the collection. We have the following theorem.

Vitali's Covering Theorem: Let $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ and let $\mathcal{F}$ be a Vitali cover of $A$. Then there exists a subcollection $\mathcal{G} \subseteq \mathcal{F}$ of pairwise disjoint intervals, such that
$
\lambda\left(A \backslash \bigcup \mathcal{G}\right)=0.
$

By considering intervals of measure at least some $\delta>0$ depending on $\epsilon$, we obtain the following.

Corollary: Let $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ be a measurable set with $\lambda(A)<\infty$, and let $\mathcal{F}$ be a Vitali cover of $A$. Then for all $\varepsilon>0$, there exists a finite subcollection $\mathcal{G}^{\prime} \subseteq \mathcal{F}$ of pairwise disjoint intervals, such that
$
\lambda\left(A \backslash \bigcup \mathcal{G}^{\prime}\right)<\varepsilon. 
$

In our case, we let $\mathcal{F}$ be the collection of interevals of form $[a, b]\subset I$ previously discussed, and let $\mathcal{G}$ be the image under $f$ of $\mathcal{F}$. So $\mathcal{G}$ is a Vitali cover of $f(I)$. Let $\mathcal{G}'$ be the finite subcollection we get for the corollary, and let $\mathcal{F}'$ be the corresponding intervals in $\mathcal{F}$. Let $G = \bigcup \mathcal{G}'$ and $F = \bigcup \mathcal{F}'$. Since the intervals of interest are now all disjoint, we have
$$
\lambda(G)>(1-\varepsilon)\lambda(f(I)),
$$
and by choosing $L$ large enough,
$$
\lambda(F)<\frac{1}{L}\lambda(I)<\frac{1}{2}\lambda(I).
$$
We can iterate the above argument, applying it to each element of $\mathcal{F}'$, since each element is a closed interval, and consider the resulting union of all intervals we get to be $F_2$. We repeat this to obtain $F_3, F_4, \dots$, noting that $I\supset F \supset F_2\supset \dots$. At each step $i$, we see that $\lambda(F_{i})<\frac{1}{2}\lambda(F_{i-1})$. Hence, on the one hand,
$$
\lambda\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^\infty F_i\right) \leq \lambda(I)\prod_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2}= 0.
$$
On the other hand, the corresponding $G_i = f(F_i)$ satisfy $\lambda(G_i)>(1-\varepsilon_i)\lambda(G_{i-1})$. We have control of $\varepsilon_i$, so we can choose a sequence $(\varepsilon_i)$ with
$$
\prod_{i=1}^\infty (1 - \varepsilon_i) > 0,
$$
so
$$
\lambda\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^\infty G_i\right) \geq \lambda(f(I))\prod_{i=1}^\infty (1 - \varepsilon_i)>0.
$$
Since $G_i = f(F_i)$, we have thus constructed a set of measure $0$ which gets mapped to a set of positive measure under $f$, as desired.
This answer was inspired by this answer by Anton Petrunin on MathOverflow.
